# Datastore projection query not returning results

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have a nested field {A: v1, B:v2, C:v3, D:v4, E:v5}, and entries are being created from ndb model class in app engine.

I need to run queries in some other application, where i need to return only certain projection. I created the suggested index, but still query returns 0 results.

*Works*: select * from Kind where E > v6.

*Works*: select A,B,D, E from kind.

*Does not work*: select A, B, D from kind where E > v6

Comment: what do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: Does not return any result. If instead of projection, I do a * like in first case, it works.

Comment: Can you show the model, the index, the query code and the entity which shows in the 1st query results but not in the 3rd?

Answer (score 0):

All of the queries in question use different sets of indexes which may have different levels of eventual consistency. See https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/ for more details about eventual consistency.

Comment: I know, first case is to show that the inequality filter should return result. Second, and third work on a single index, that was suggested for the third query. But second query does return result, while the last one doesnt